# Odd circles and doubly covered edges

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G= (V,E)$ be a simple, undirected graph. A set $C\subseteq V$ is said to be an *edge cover* if for all $e\in E$ we have $e\cap C \neq \emptyset$.

It is most satisfying to find an edge cover $C$ such that every edge is covered exactly once (that is, $|C\cap e| = 1$ for all $e\in E$) --  but unfortunately this is only possible if $G$ does not contain odd circles (i.e. $\chi(G) \leq 2$).

However: given any graph $G$, is it always possible to find an edge cover $C\subseteq V(G)$ such that the number of edges $e\in E$ with $e\subseteq C$ is at most the number of odd circles in $G$?

Comment: I guess $C\subset V$

Comment: Sorry - thanks I will correct this!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a triangular prism with $6$ vertices and $9$ edges. You need to pick two vertices from each triangle and that also chooses both ends of another edge.   That is a problem if you view it as two odd cycles (the triangles. ) I suppose there are 8 odd cycles if you include the $5$-cycles.

Of course with $n$ edges all on one vertex you can get a satisfying edge cover using $1$  vertex and another using $n$ vertices.

Similarly, there many be many different (size) sets $D$ of edges including at least one from each odd cycle. For each one there is an edge cover that uses both vertices of each edge in $D$ but only one vertex from every other edge (except those with both ends also on edges in $D$)

**LATER**

Actually it is somewhat more complicated than that. And the original question is still not answered. I reformulated the question with some variations [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261072/bipartite-defect-in-graphs).

Comment: Thanks - and great follow-up question! I read your previous answer too superficially, I'm sorry!